# MAC OS X bundle with files supposed to reside in /Library Directory

Tags: macos, installation, bundle

I am new to MAC OS X. I have created a bundle for my app, but two files need to remain in the following two dirs:

```
/Library/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/

/Library/Internet Plugin's/
```

Both the directories need root access to copy files into them. The first directory may not even exist and needs to be created.

In windows or Linux - setups or deb/rpm packages, it's pretty simple, but I couldn't figure out a way in MAC as every thing is contained in the bundle itself.

Comment: Are you sure those files wouldn't work from the `~/Library` directory as well?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, I am sure atleast Opera requires manifest file to be in /Library/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/
It doesn't work otherwise

Comment: Then you are forced to provide installation code within your app and that will require privilege escalation, and that's not trivial.

Comment: @trojanfoe I am disappointed, can you please guide me to the appropriate links.

Answer (score 0):

This amazing free app **"Package"** solved my problem

http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html

Comment: This solved your problem in 15 minutes (the time between your comment above, and this answer)?